# infinite scroll: array list not render in *ngFor after adding the element in array on scroll end

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i am render the array of list using ngFor. i am using infinite scroll and add the new elements on scroll end. but after adding the new elements in array, the render is not happened and it only update when i click on any were in page.

file.html

```
<div *ngIf="arrayList.length">
   <ul class="max-h-400" infinite-scroll (scrollEnd)="onScrollFunc()">
       <li *ngFor="let item of arrayList;let i = index">
           <div>item.name</div>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

file.ts

```
onScrollFunc() {
this.getNewElemList(reqObj)
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      if (response && response.data) {
        if (this.arrayList && this.arrayList.length) {
          this.arrayList.push(...response.data);
        } else {
          this.arrayList = response.data;
        }
      }
    },
    () => {
       console.log('error');
    }
  );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, change detection does not fire if you push to an array. Since the bound object is the array, the array has to change its refrence.
So instead of arrayList.push do it like this:
this.arrayList = [...this.arrayList, ...response.data]. This creates a new array which triggers the change detection to render again

Comment: i tied this also but still facing the same issue. i checked the array is updated but Dom is not rendering

Comment: Is your change detection set to default or OnPush?

Comment: actually i have some default list and after scroll-end i need to add more element in the list. it should update when i get the data from service

Comment: could you create a stackblitz of the part of your application?

Comment: i can't create it. without that can't u check the issue